# Colon Operator factor:list

Tags: r

In case where f1 and f2 are integers,
I know f1:f2 represent list of integers from a to b with difference of 1. In case where a and b are both factors, f1:f2 represent a new factor with levels of each unique combination of factor levels of f1 and f2 (an interaction) as seen below. **What if I use f1:x where x is a list as oppose to a factor?**

```
f1<-gl(2,3) #create factor with 2 levels 
f2<-gl(3,2) #create factor with 3 levels 
x<-rnorm(6) #create list with 6 real numbers(sampled from normal)

> f1
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
Levels: 1 2

> f2
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3

> x
[1]  0.6705013 -0.2116773 -0.3812724 -0.3687866  1.4878815  0.3095373

f1:f2

[1] 1:1 1:1 1:2 2:2 2:3 2:3
Levels: 1:1 1:2 1:3 2:1 2:2 2:3

f1:x

[1] 1
Warning messages:
1: In f1:x : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
2: In f1:x : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
```

As you can see, I get an output of 1 with warning message. **What is happening?**

Comment: Did you check out the `?":"` help page? There are only special versions for numeric values or `factors`. You can't really mix and match. With factors, `:` is basically a shortcut for `interaction()`. Basically the behavior when mixing data types is undefined. What were you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Some experimentation suggests that `R` is coercing the expressions on either side of the colon to numeric, taking the first element of each expression, and then evaluating the expression with the colon as `seq(from, to)`.  E.g.

```
> factor(c("C","B","A")):(7:8)
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

In your example, `1: 0.6705013` evaluates to `1`.